# Backbone.js how to work with fetched Items

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js

I'm trying to learn Backbone.js and I seem to be having an issue with fetch on a model. I have:

```
window.News = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: "/rest/news"
});

window.NewsItems = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: News,
    url: "/rest/news"
});

window.NewsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $(".newsItem"),

    events: {
        "click .edit": "editNews" 
    },

    editTemplate: $('#tmpl-edit-news-item').template(),

    editNews: function(evt) {
        console.log("EDIT CLICKED");
        var ele = $(evt.target);
        var news = new News({id:1});
        news.fetch();
        console.log(news);
        console.log(news.get('title');
     }

});

new NewsView();
```

I have an elements on page that have a class="edit" data-id="$ID". When I click the element everything goes as expected. Backbone runs the editNews function, "EDIT CLICKED" shows up in the console and console.log(news) outputs an object. Inside that object I noticed there is an attributes field that contains the json of the news item loaded by the server. So the server is working and sending back json. There is a title field that is set to "Test News Title", but running console.log(news.get('title')) returns undefined.

Do I need to pass the fetched data to something to turn it into a backbone model? I thought using fetch took the json data thats returned and put it into the model.

Additional Info:

```
url requested: http://localhost/rest/news/1  
response data: {"class":"org.backbonetest.News","id":1,"content":"This is test content","dateCreated":"2011-09-20T16:19:56Z","lastUpdated":"2011-09-20T16:19:56Z","shortDescription":"","title":"Test News Title"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
editNews: function(evt) {
    console.log("EDIT CLICKED");
    var ele = $(evt.target);
    var news = new News({id:1});

    // fetch is asynchronous process so we will bind handler to model's change event
    news.bind('change', function(model, value) {
        console.log(news);
        console.log(news.get('title');
    }, this)
    news.fetch();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay so since the fetch is asynchronous, I can't call console.log on it right away. Adding a success function allows the object to work as a model.

```
var news = new News({id:1});
news.fetch();
console.log(news);
console.log(news.get('title');
```

Becomes

```
news.fetch({success: function() {
                        console.log(news.get("title"));
                     },
                     processData: true
           });
```

This returns the proper title.

Comment: what is `processData` in fetch options?

Comment: I don't think I'd do it this way.  See what @ant_Ti is suggesting.  The "backbone" way is to bind to the "change" or "reset" events on your model/collection.  From a view, you would often bind to "render" and the render function would update that part of the view.  The "success" callback is usually used for other things.